# Cordova fastlane xcode 8 configure profile

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, certificate, code-signing

I try to build my app via fastlane (https://github.com/platanus/fastlane-cordova) on xcode 8
How can I specify in cordova to select the "correct" provisioning profiles when geenerating the xcode.proj?

```
=== BUILD TARGET app OF PROJECT app WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
[ios] 
[ios] Check dependencies
[ios] Signing for "Eule" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
[ios] Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
[ios] 
[ios] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ios] 
[ios] 
[ios] The following build commands failed:
[ios]   Check dependencies
[ios] (1 failure)
[ios] Error: Error code 65 for command
```

Comment: https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html

Comment: What about https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/migrating_code_signing.html#manual-signing-xcode-8 manual configuration? How can I specify that in the build.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, so I ended up creating a [Cordova plugin for Fastlane](https://github.com/bamlab/fastlane-plugin-cordova) to solve this.

See how to use it in [this blog post](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/deploy-a-new-cordova-app-to-testflight-in-5-minutes-with-fastlane) or below:

### Use the Cordova Fastlane plugin

Add the [Cordova Fastlane Plugin](https://github.com/Almouro/fastlane-plugin-cordova) to your project:

```
fastlane add_plugin cordova
```

When asked `Should fastlane modify the Gemfile at path 'Gemfile' for you? (y/n)`, reply with `y`.

Then you can integrate the plugin into your Fastlane setup, for example:

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Deploy ios app on the appstore"

  lane :create do
    produce(app_name: "myapp")
  end

  lane :deploy do
    match(
      type: "appstore",
      git_url: "https://bitbucket.org/Almouro/certificates" # REPLACE WITH YOUR PRIVATE REPO FOR MATCH
    )
    cordova(platform: 'ios') # Using the Cordova Fastlane Plugin
    appstore(ipa: ENV['CORDOVA_IOS_RELEASE_BUILD_PATH'])
  end
end

platform :android do
  desc "Deploy android app on play store"

  lane :deploy do
    cordova(
      platform: 'android',
      keystore_path: './prod.keystore', # REPLACE THESE LINES WITH YOUR KEYSTORE INFORMATION
      keystore_alias: 'prod',
      keystore_password: 'password'
    ) # Cordova Fastlane Plugin
    supply(apk: ENV['CORDOVA_ANDROID_RELEASE_BUILD_PATH'])
  end
end
```

with an `Appfile` such as

```
app_identifier "com.awesome.app"
apple_id "apple@id.com"
team_id "28323HT"
```

**Piece of cake now!**

For iOS, run `fastlane ios create` once to create your app on the developer member center and iTunes Connect.

Now, you only have to run `fastlane ios deploy` and `fastlane android deploy` to deploy to the stores!

### Where to go from here

- You can see all the plugin options by running `fastlane actions cordova` at the root of your Cordova app
- The [Fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools) are great to learn more about how it can ease your life
- If you have any issue or idea for improvement on the plugin, please make them know [here](https://github.com/bamlab/fastlane-plugin-cordova/issues)

Comment: @leonziyo noo! can you open [an issue on the repo](https://github.com/bamlab/fastlane-plugin-cordova/issues)? We'll figure this out :)

Comment: sorry about that it was my mistake something unrelated to this. It is now working!

Comment: @leonziyo great! glad to hear it :)